# How to analyze ndm logs in cdunix to know number of files successfully sent out?

Tags: linux

I tried using:

`grep "MSST=Copy step successful" filename`

But it's not giving me the desired results.

Comment: I think even on SuperUser you'll have to rephrase your question a bit... ie, what are your desired results?

Comment: Connect direct is used to transfer files from one system to another.Its logs are formed under ndm directory on daily basis.I want to know from the logs ,the total number of files successfully transferred.